# casting and setting ImageView from a loop

Tags: android, android-imageview

I came across to the sample below but not sure how the 2 dimension array is declared `(buttons[i][j])` and if I can use instead of buttons `ImageViews` with id in xml file named as `w1_1, w1_2, ...to w1_7` ending with `w5_7;` (5 rows by 7) 35 in total. I have tried the sample below but crush at runtime,  `buttons[i][j].setOnClickListener(this);` show error

```
for(int i=0; i<some_value; i++) {
for(int j=0; j<some_other_value; j++) {
String buttonID = "btn" + i + "-" + j;
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(buttonID, "id", getPackageName());
buttons[i][j] = ((Button) findViewById(resID));
buttons[i][j].setOnClickListener(this);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First:
To declare 2 dimensional array...

```
Button[][] a = new Button[x][y];
```

Second:
To get resources I'd you can take a look at R class you will find your ids value like

```
likeBtn = 00000000;
shareBtn = 00000001;
```

*Note* They will be in the same sequence if you define them Sequentially (drag first one then second then third and so on).

Then you can use the first id as start point and increment it until reach to end.

Comment: can you elaborate a little? x,y dimension like 4,5 in a matrix 4x5? 
Why this is marked error buttons[i][j].setOnClickListener(this);

Comment: yes (x , y ) is the dimensions of your array, what is the error can you post your log?!